# Get Value of attribute from an array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows:

```
data = [
 {
  "tag":"A"
 },
 {
  "tag":"B"
 },
 {
  "tag":"C"
 }
];
```

I want these tags' values in another array. I know I can do it using `forEach` loop but want to do it in some other efficient way. Any way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use a `.map()` call for this instead of `.forEach()`. See the [MDN article for `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
data = [
 {
  "tag":"A"
 },
 {
  "tag":"B"
 },
 {
  "tag":"C"
 }
];

const tags = data.map(el => el.tag);
console.log(tags)
```

Rather than having to create a temporary array, the `.map()` function transforms each value in an existing array into a new array. In this case, you just take the `.tag` property of every old element to make the new element.